# Android coverflow jumping on downloaded /disk images

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, coverflow

I'm using this coverflow widget: http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

with images downloaded from the internet. Works almost fine.

The problem is that the coverflow jumps/stumbles a bit when the images are downloaded from the web or fetched from disk. I'm doing this in a separate thread, and set in imageView with handler, etc. this system works perfectly, fluently, everywhere else, listview, gridview, etc.

I even switched to this library for the image handling: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, which seems to handle all the threading and caching very well.

But still the same.

One solution, is to prefetch all the images and put them in memory. As long as the coverflow gets the images from the memory cache, it's fluent. But the number of images is obviously limited, because of memory limits. I tried with LruCache. But well, as expected, as soon as the memory images have to be cleared from memory and fetched from disk/web again, the jumping appears.

Anyone else had this? Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Can you answer my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547838/not-showing-cache-or-downloaded-images-in-fancycoverflow

Comment: I don't know fancyCoverFlow. This question is about a different library, and so far I understand from your question, a different problem. I can't help.

Comment: fancyCoverFlow is same as Coverflow , Thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: Mhh ok, it has been I while since I did Android dev... you seem to have an own version of createReflectedImages? Does it work with the method in the library? I would suggest to reduce your createReflectedImages to the bare minimum (just showing the bitmap without reflection) and starting from there, if that works advance step by step until the problem appears, so you know exactly which call causes the problem. This will also help your readers...